# Ajax call when user presses back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, back-button, pageload

I have a problem in my current application. I load lots of page content via ajax and it works always as expected. However, every time user visits another page of my application and clicks back button, those ajax calls is sent every time.  I found myself deleting all of the content before ajax call and load it after that. Is there a simple way for such a case ? I mean, I would like to know if there is a way that I can be informed as back button is clicked so I don't need to make another ajax call ?

This is html file:

```
<div id="contentToBeLoaded">

</div>
```

It's my current java script now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#contentToBeLoaded").empty(); // This is to the handle back button is clicked

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/pageToLoadContent',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $("#contentToBeLoaded").html(html);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can try window.onunload

Comment: Try reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601879/html5-refresh-page-when-popstate-is-fired

Comment: if customer go to another page and back the event ready fire again. because the page load new page again.. Do you need implement a pushState api using 1 single page for all app.